# Nginx: rewriting while checking args format with a regex

Tags: nginx, fastcgi, nginx-reverse-proxy, ngx-http-rewrite-module

I have an API endpoint like `/my/api/PARAM1/abcd?arg1=val1&arg2=val2`, and use a redirect to proxy to a fastcgi server elsewhere (using upstream).

Basically I have the current configuration :

```
location ~ "^/my/api/(?<api_name>[A-Z0-9]+)?$" {
    rewrite ^ "/cgi-bin/apiserver?api_name=${api_name}&p1=${arg_arg1}&p2=${arg_arg2}" last;
}

location /cgi-bin/apiserver {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_index myapiserver?*;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/lib/cgi-bin/myapiserver$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_pass my_fcgi_upstream;
}
```

The FCGI server is not something I control, I can't change the arguments names in the query string, nor the code it runs. I would like to protect it against attacks, like checking the format of the GET args sent to it (`arg1` and `arg2` in this example, sent as `p1` and `p2`). Checking that they are real numbers, or that the string formats complies with a specific regex.

Ideally I also would like to check that a couple of parameters `(p1, p2, p3, p4)` lies in a specific whitelist (for example `(0,1,2,3)` is allowed but not `(1,1,2,3)`.

For the first problem, I think we would achieve something using several location blocks or rewrites, but I can't find the correct way to do that.
For the second improvement (params whitelist), I guess my only solution is to rely on some kind of Lua scripting in nginx? I would like to avoid at all costs to have some kind of applicative proxy between the FCGI server and nginx, so if I could do everyting within nginx, it would be awesome!

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Nginx uses a normalised URI when testing the regular expressions in the `location` block or `rewrite` statement. The arguments have been removed at this stage, and relocated to the `$args` and `$arg_` variables.

The only effective way to test arguments is with an `if` statement, with or without [a `map` block](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map).

You could check the arguments at any point in your configuration, but assuming you want to check it as close to the `fastcgi_pass` as possible, you would place an `if ... { return ...; }` block inside the `location /cgi-bin/apiserver` block. Note that this is one of the valid cases for [using `if` within a `location` block](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/).

The final part of the question is best achieved using a `map` as you can concatenate `p1`, `p2`, `p3` and `p4` into a single string and run it past multiple regular expressions.

For example:

```
map $arg_p1,$arg_p2,$arg_p3,$arg_p4 $fails {
~^1,2,3,4$  0;
default     1;
}

server {
    ...

    location /cgi-bin/apiserver {
        if (fails) { return 403; }
        ...
    }
}
```

You could also test `p1` and `p2` individually using the same map, by using `.*` in the other positions. But it's probably unnecessary as they must be numbers to match the whitelist anyway.

Note that the `map` block must be placed **outside** the `server` block. Also, note that regular expressions are evaluated in order until a match is found.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer, I didn't think of using `if` as it's usually evil :). I'll give it a try.